# Execute Urban Airship cURL command in nodejs using request?

Tags: node.js, curl, request, urbanairship.com

I am trying to execute a cURL command that will send a push notification. I have the cURL command that will do it, but now i just need to execute it in node.

The current cURL is:

```
curl -v -X POST -u "<shared>:<secret>" -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;" --data '{"audience" : {"tag":[testTag]}, "device_types" : "all", "notification" : {"alert": "Test push notification"} }' https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/"
```

And my current request in node is:

```
            request({
              url: "https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/",
              method: "POST",
              json: {
                audience : {
                    tag : [ "testTag" ]
                }, 
                device_types : "all", 
                notification : {
                    alert : "Test push notification"
                } 
              }
            });
```

I'm not sure how to pass the shared and secret, or even if this is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

[This `request` example](https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication) shows how to do HTTP authentication. In short, add at least `auth: { user: 'shared', password: 'secret' }` to your `request()` options.

There is also an [example for adding custom HTTP headers](https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers). That's as simple as setting `headers: { 'Accept': 'application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;' }` in your `request()` options. The `Content-Type` header should be automatically set by `request` when you use the `json` option as you currently are.